# displaying results from $_post gone wrong, gives empty

Tags: php, mysql

I got this code for getting the category name and show the items in this category:

```
<?php 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$cat_list="";
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$cat_sql="SELECT * FROM products,prod_cat,categories WHERE categories.id=prod_cat.cat_id AND products.id=prod_cat.prod_id AND categories.id=$cat";
$cat_query=mysql_query($cat_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$results=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat_query);
$cat_list= "$results[cat_name]";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>show</title>

</head>
<?php echo $cat_list; ?>

</html>
```

it gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: cat in show.php on line 12
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

All I need is to display the `cat_name` out of the categories from the `$cat` variable like `show.php?cat=6`.

Comment: you need `$_GET['cat']` not post then and better only call your database after: a) you santitized (escaped) your $cat variable, b) $cat is not empty()

Comment: variable like show.php?cat=6 is get request, try to use $_GET array

Comment: use $_GET["cat"] instead of $_POST["cat"];

Comment: You need to check $_POST['cat']; post variable name is cat ?

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` are not the same. In this case you are trying to access **cat** in `show.php?cat=6`, so you should use `$_GET['cat']`.

Generally:

- $_GET retrieves variables from the querystring, or your URL.
- $_POST retrieves variables from a POST method, such as forms.

PHP.net manual:
**$_GET** - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
`An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.`

**$_POST** - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
`An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.`

Answer (score 1):

First use $_GET or $_REQUST instead of $_POST. And also make sure you protect your input. Try this function:

```
function protect($string){
    $string = urldecode($string); // url decode to make things like %20 into whitespace
    $string = trim(strip_tags($string)); //remove whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/'/", "", $string); //remove single quotes
    return $string;
}
```

and use it like this

```
$cat = protect($_REQUEST['cat']);
```

Lastly, I think there is a syntax here here.
This line here

```
$cat_list= "$results[cat_name]";
```

Should Be

```
$cat_list= $results['cat_name'];
```

It was looking for a constant called cat_name. The keys of arrays are always strings. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
$cat = "";
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $cat=$_GET['cat'];
}
```

Comment: now i need to show the picture of the product, which is named with the id number. doesnt work like this: $cat_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - <img src=inventory_images/'$id'.jpg"> <br />";

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not get $cat value, change it to `$_GET`;
2. To make sure, your query doesn't break like that in the future, ad `'` to ids too:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
    ,prod_cat
    ,categories
WHERE
    categories.id=prod_cat.cat_id
    AND products.id=prod_cat.prod_id
    AND categories.id='$cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
show.php?cat=6
```

in your url means you are using a `GET` variable. use

```
$_GET['cat']
```

Furthermore:

1. PLEASE do something about security. People can put anything they want into that GET variable, so they can add what they want to your SQL!! THIS IS BAD!
2. Please, read the notice on the PHP manual page of the `mysql*` functions: they are deprecated and should not be used. Use PDO or MySQLi